# Proper slider in a Windows 10 contextmenu

Tags: c#, wpf, slider, contextmenu, notifyicon

I use this [NotifyIcon Nuget](http://www.hardcodet.net/wpf-notifyicon). And created a Context Menu with some different elements in it. (`MenuItem, TextBox, Separator, TextBlock, Grid, Slider`)

In Windows 7 every thing shows like i want to. (TextBox with `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` use all the space which is free, Slider too, Grid spread also streched)

But in Windows 10 it don't strech. The Textboxes expand if I type a Text that need more space, so thats ok. But the slider is only 1px long, so you can set it to ON/OFF instead of 0 to 255. And the Grid looks ugly.

[Win 7 picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grvdq.png) [Win 10 picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnCtd.png)

Here is my Code:

```
<Window x:Class="ContextMenu.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:tb="http://www.hardcodet.net/taskbar"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ContextMenu"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="1" Width="100"
        AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" Background="Black"
        Top="0" 
        Left="0" 
        Topmost="True" ShowInTaskbar="False">
    <Grid>
        <tb:TaskbarIcon x:Name="MyNotifyIcon"
                        IconSource="/Icons/Ninja.ico"
                        ToolTipText="Overlay">
            <tb:TaskbarIcon.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem x:Name="CheckPing" IsCheckable="True" Header="Ping"></MenuItem>
                    <TextBox x:Name="TextPing" Text="8.8.8.8" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                    <Separator/>
                    <TextBlock Text="Set the Position"/>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBox x:Name="WindowTop" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="0"></TextBox>
                        <TextBox x:Name="WindowLeft" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="1" Text="0"></TextBox>
                    </Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="Set the Opacity"/>
                    <Slider x:Name="SliderOpacity" Minimum="0" Maximum="255" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"></Slider>
                    <TextBlock Text="Set the Fontsize"/>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="10"></TextBlock>
                        <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="+"></Button>
                        <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="-"></Button>
                    </Grid>
                    <MenuItem Header="Exit"></MenuItem>
                </ContextMenu>
            </tb:TaskbarIcon.ContextMenu>
        </tb:TaskbarIcon>
        <StackPanel x:Name="VerticalStackLong">
            <StackPanel x:Name="HorizontalStack" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackPanel x:Name="MainGrid"></StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to just set the "MinWidth".

for example:

```
<Slider x:Name="SliderOpacity" Minimum="0" Maximum="255" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="80"></Slider>
```

I did not found a better solution until now.